# Why can't I import this Zope component in a Python 2.4 virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, zope

I'm trying to install Plone 3.3rc4 with plone.app.blob and repoze but nothing I've tried has worked so far. For one attempt I've pip-installed repoze.zope2, Plone, and plone.app.blob into a virtualenv. I have [this version of DocumentTemplate](http://svn.zope.org/Zope/trunk/lib/python/DocumentTemplate/?rev=96249) in the virtualenv's site-packages directory and I'm trying to get it running in RHEL5.

For some reason when I try to run `paster serve etc/zope2.ini` in this environment way Python gives the message `ImportError: No module named DT_Util`? `DT_Util.py` exists in the directory, `__init__.py` is there too, and the C module it depends on is there. I suspect there's some circular dependency or failure when importing the C extension. Of course this module would work in a normal Zope install...

```
>>> import DocumentTemplate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "DocumentTemplate/__init__.py", line 21, in ?
  File ".../lib/python2.4/site-packages/DocumentTemplate/DocumentTemplate.py", line 112, in ?
    from DT_String import String, File
  File ".../lib/python2.4/site-packages/DocumentTemplate/DT_String.py", line 19, in ?
    from DocumentTemplate.DT_Util import ParseError, InstanceDict
ImportError: No module named DT_Util
```

Comment: Why don't you follow up your own questions? -1

Comment: I did edit the question in an attempt to make it more clear. I'm not sure this is a sound installation method. I've tried lots of different buildouts and have been unable to get plone.app.blob and repoze working at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I must say I doubt DocumentTemplate from Zope will work standalone. You are welcome to try though. :-)

Note that [DT_Util imports C extensions](https://github.com/zopefoundation/DocumentTemplate/blob/master/src/DocumentTemplate/DT_Util.py#L32-L34):

```
from DocumentTemplate.cDocumentTemplate import InstanceDict, TemplateDict
from DocumentTemplate.cDocumentTemplate import render_blocks, safe_callable
from DocumentTemplate.cDocumentTemplate import join_unicode
```

You'll need to make sure those are compiled. My guess is that importing the `cDocumentTemplate` module fails and thus the import of `DT_Util` fails.

Comment: It is compiled but it fails anyway.

Comment: And those C extensions themselves import just fine? Try import DocumentTemplate.cDocumentTemplate.

Comment: No, if I try `from DocumentTemplate import cDocumentTemplate` I get the same `ImportError: No module named DT_Util` message.